# Multiply values of two files - but keep the decimal places

Tags: shell-script, awk

I have **file1.txt**

```
0.1234
0.333
0.22
0.1
```

and **file2.txt**

```
2
10
100
100
```

I'm looking for a command that multiplies the lines with each other and outputs as many decimal places as file1.txt had at this position/line.
**output.txt**

```
0.2468
3.330
22.00
10.0
```

so far i use this command:
`paste file1.txt file2.txt | awk '{printf "%.4f", ($1 * $2)}' > output.txt`
But of course "%.4f" always produces 4 decimal places...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your awk implementation provides access to the underlying C library's dynamic width and precision features, **and the numbers in `file1.txt` can never include mantissa-exponent representations like `1.23e4`**, then you could do something like

```
$ paste file1.txt file2.txt | 
  awk '{split($1,a,/[.]/); printf "%.*f\n", length(a[2]), ($1 * $2)}'
0.2468
3.330
22.00
10.0
```

or perhaps a little more robustly

```
paste file1.txt file2.txt | 
  awk '{l = (match($1,/[.][[:digit:]]+/) > 0) ? RLENGTH-1 : 0; 
  printf "%.*f\n", l, ($1 * $2)
}'
```

Comment: [never+name+a+variable+l](https://www.google.com/search?q=never+name+a+variable+l)

Comment: `awk` commands in both answers are very good. I've upvoted both. But I would be happier if explained.

Comment: @PrabhjotSingh we can't explain basic awk syntax in every answer but feel free to ask questions if you have any after taking a look at the man pages

Answer (score 3):

With `paste` + `bc`:

```
$ paste -d '*' file1.txt file2.txt | bc
.2468
3.330
22.00
10.0
```

The number of decimal places on output will be the max of those of the two operands, not necessarily those of the first.

Pipe to `sed -E 's/^(-?)\./\10./'` to get `0.2468` in place of `.2468` (or `-0.1` in place of `-.1`).

With `awk`:

```
$ awk -F. '{getline x < "file2.txt"; printf "%.*f\n", length($2), $0*x}' file1.txt
0.2468
3.330
22.00
10.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk '
    NR==FNR { mult[NR]=$1; next }
    {
        prec = ( /\./ ? length($1)-index($1,".") : 0 )
        printf "%.*f\n", prec, $1 * mult[FNR]
    }
' file2.txt file1.txt
0.2468
3.330
22.00
10.0
```